# Typescript keeps adding a function above the imports

Tags: typescript

When typescript compiles the Javascript it's adding this function at the top

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    }
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
import { PortWidget } from "storm-react-diagrams";
```

So then I get the error

> Line 14:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "sourceMap": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "watch": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // "resolveJsonModule": true,
    //"noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "desktop",
    "public",
    "mobile",
    "tests",
    "src/player/*"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/admin/react"
  ]
}
```

Any idea how I fix this?

I can't see why this extend function is getting added each time.

Comment: Perhaps __extends is only generated when you're using namespaces (internal modules)? I could be wrong but check if you have any namespaces defined, it's not advised when using external modules.

Comment: Looks like eslint rules are being run on the emitted javascript. You will want to look into how to disable that and only run linting on the typescript code. Another thing you could try is to turn on the `--importHelpers` (`"importHelpers": true`) compiler option and add [tslib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslib) to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the compilation, TypeScript can generate helpers like `__extends` to make sure the related feature will work in runtime. You can think of them as polyfills.

By default, helpers will be inlined in every file that needs them. In your case, that's every file that uses the `extends` clause.

You can opt out of this behavior and supply the required helpers yourself — only this time they will be imported just once. Use the `--importHelpers` to make TypeScript pull them from `tslib` for you.

**`tsconfig.json`**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "importHelpers": true,
    ...
  }    
}
```

Remember to install `tslib` in your project:

```sh
npm install tslib
```

Read more about compiler options in the [Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).